# unable to print username for person texting in slack bot

Tags: python, slack

how to get username like "Jonh" instead of WLLACM2HK??

code

```
starterbot_id = web_client.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
print("starterbot id------->"+starterbot_id))
```

current output for above code

```
starterbot id------->WLLACM2HK
```

I want code to print something like below output

```
starterbot id------->Jonh
```

data in web_client.api_call("auth.test")

```
{
    'ok': True,
    'url': 'https: //bby-sandbox-general.slack.com/',
    'team': 'SandboxGeneralWorkspace',
    'user': 'ipt-autobot',
    'team_id': 'TFHGD33RV',
    'user_id': 'WLLACM2HK',
    'bot_id': 'BLDVB7EKB',
    'enterprise_id': 'EFGBDRLNP',
    'warning': 'superfluous_charset',
    'response_metadata': {
        'warnings': [
            'superfluous_charset'
        ]
    }
}
```

I feel im not calling the right api , because i dont see the username in above json , the user attribute is actually the name of the slack bot , im looking to print the user who is texting in the slack bot

on trying  print(web_client.users_info(user=user))

```
{
    'ok': True,
    'user': {
        'id': 'WGUHC67D1',
        'team_id': 'TJK2GBSC9',
        'name': 'a6002043',
        'deleted': False,
        'color': 'c386df',
        'real_name': 'RaviKanth',
        'tz': 'America/Chicago',
        'tz_label': 'CentralStandardTime',
        'tz_offset': -21600,
        'profile': {
            'title': 'CW-Other',
            'phone': '+15614128585',
            'skype': '',
            'real_name': 'RaviKanth',
            'real_name_normalized': 'RaviKanth',
            'display_name': 'RaviKanth',
            'display_name_normalized': 'RaviKanth',
            'status_text': '',
            'status_emoji': '',
            'status_expiration': 0,
            'avatar_hash': '8f97c61708c1',
            'image_original': 'https: //avatars.slack-edge.com/2019-11-27/852421659589_8f97c61708c1553628c8_original.jpg',
            'is_custom_image': True,
```

how grab real_name value and print it?

Comment: what is the output of `web_client.api_call("auth.test")` ?

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini - added the output of web_client.api_call("auth.test") and in that json i dont see any username related attribute , so do you know what to call?

Comment: `auth.test` 'checks authentication and tells "you" who you are, even if you might be a bot.' In this case, the username is the value `user`. This is the username of your bot. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I can't help you figure out what else you need to call. Take a look at the docs. https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test

Comment: @user1558604  , I want to print username (example: John ) instead of  'WLLACM2HK', from user_id  . But username attribute is not available in api im calling , So do you know which api i can call instead?   the user attribute is actually bot name and not the person name texting in that bot

Comment: I don't use the slack api, but checking their website, maybe https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity,

Comment: @user1558604 ok how to call user.identity?  i tried printing  web_client.api_call("users.identity")  but i got :The request to the Slack API failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just working on it, If you have `user_id` then you can use `user.info` method to get specific user information.

Here is an example:
[image]

Link: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info

Comment: on trying  to print(web_client.users_info(user=user)) i see the json you mentioned in you image , So can you please help me with the code on how grab real_name attribute value and print it   (edited my question for reference)

Comment: for example a=your_json_result then you have to do like print(a['user']['real_name'])

Comment: If this answer solve your problem please mark it as answer.